# Asymptotic behavior of an inverse function

Tags: probability, analysis, algorithms, asymptotics, cryptography

I am interested in hashing recently, and encountered an interesting estimate that deals with birthday problem. The original context is not relevant to the estimate I want, so I omit it unless people are interested in. The estimate I like to get is:

#### Question

For the function $$P(N,d)=\frac{N!}{d!N^d},$$ what's the asymptotic behavior of the inverse function $d(P,N)$?

#### Attempt

Using Stirling's formula, I have $$\frac{N!}{P}\sim\sqrt{2\pi d}\frac{Nd}{e}^d,$$ but I have no idea how to proceed.

#### Example

More specifically, I would like to obtain for what $d$ is the probability $P$ less than $10^{-4}$, where $N$ is assumed to be, say, $2^{128}$. This relates to how safety the algorithm [`MD5`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is.

Comment: How does d compare with N?

Comment: It's open. I don't require the scale of $d$ to do with that of $N$. However, I would expect in application $P$, and thus $d$ comparing to $N$, is required to be small.

Answer (score 1):

From
$P(N,d)
=\frac{N!}{d!N^d},
$,
$\ln(P)
=\ln(N!)-\ln(d!)-d\ln(N)
$.

Since
$\ln(x!)
=x\ln(x)-x+O(\ln(x))
$,

$\ln(P)
=N\ln(N)-N+O(\ln(N))-(d\ln(d)-d+O(\ln(d))-d\ln(N)
$.

Let 
$d = \dfrac{c}{\ln(c)}
$
so
$d\ln(d)
= \dfrac{c}{\ln(c)}(\ln(c)-\ln\ln(c))
=c-\dfrac{c\ln\ln(c)}{\ln(c)}
=c+o(c)
$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(P)
&=N\ln(N)-N+O(\ln(N))-(d\ln(d)-d+O(\ln(d))-d\ln(N)\\
&=N\ln(N)-N+O(\ln(N))-(c+o(c))-\dfrac{c}{\ln(c)}\ln(N)\\
&=N\ln(N)+o(N)-c+o(c)-\dfrac{c}{\ln(c)}\ln(N)\\
\end{array}
$

If
$d = o(N)$,
then
$\ln(P)
=N\ln(N)-c+o(N)+o(c)-o(N\ln(N))
$
so
$c
=N\ln(N)-\ln(P)+o(N\ln(N))
$
so
$\ln(c)
=\ln(N)+o(\ln(N))
$
so
$d 
=\dfrac{c}{\ln(c)}
=\dfrac{N\ln(N)-\ln(P)+o(N\ln(N))}{\ln(N)+o(\ln(N))}
=N-\dfrac{\ln(P)}{\ln(N)}+o(N)
$.

Anyway,
the answer should be
something like this.

Comment: How did you get the formula for $ln(x!)$ on the second line, and could you please explain how you came out the trick letting $d = \frac{c}{\ln c}$?

Comment: The first is just Stirling, and the second is "well known" - I first saw it in de Bruijn's "Asymptomatic Methods in Analysis".

Comment: minor problem: $-N$ in the formula for $ln(P)$ is not absorbed in to $o(N)$, but anyway it is absorbed into $o(Nln(N))$ in the formula for $c$ afterward.

Comment: What concerns me **more** is where does the error $o(c)$ in the last two lines go? At the end, if carefully written, we look at $d=\frac{c+o(c)}{ln(c+o(c))}$ where $o(c)/ln(c)$ might explode.